# Javascript Functions across iFrames involving social authentication

Tags: php, javascript, social-networking

I have reverse engineered a system designed to allow website log in using various social networks. The system used pop up windows for the authentication system on each social network. I want to change this to iFrames. I had a play with the code but am struggling substantially.

The problem lies in these functions. The first one is in the authentication.php file:

```
function init() {
    window.opener.wsl_wordpress_social_login({
        'action'   : 'wordpress_social_login',
        'provider' : '<?php echo $provider ?>'
    });

    window.close();
}
```

the second in the connect.js file:

```
window.wsl_wordpress_social_login = function(config) {...
```

I changed them to this, but with no avail.

```
function init() {
    wsl_wordpress_social_login({
        'action'   : 'wordpress_social_login',
        'provider' : '<?php echo $provider ?>'
    });
}
```

and

```
wsl_wordpress_social_login = function(config) {
```

I also tried changing to window.parent.document and that did not work either.

The error returned by FireBug is this: `wsl_wordpress_social_login is not defined`

For development purposes the iframe ID is `#iframe`

Comment: I havn't used the google maps API, so I can't give you an answer, but I'd like to give you this advice: google maps lets you get a route given start and endlocation, and some other optional parameters. The purpost of client side scripting is to make the client do the heavy lifting for their own requests, so if you just store the parameters you used to get the route, you should be able to make the client show it to the user.

Comment: Is the iframe content on the same host as your scripts?

Comment: @lgnas .. O yes it is. The problem is in recognising the function since it was undefined.

Comment: @FrederikCreemers What the hell are you on about

Comment: srry, clicked wrong link, wanted to comment on another question.

Answer (score 0):

The Javascript needs `window.wsl_wordpress_social_login = function(config) {`

The PHP file needs :

```
function init() {
    window.parent.window.wsl_wordpress_social_login({
        'action'   : 'wordpress_social_login',
        'provider' : '<?php echo $provider ?>'
    });
}
```

Marvellous